# Contact form with check boxes almost working

Tags: php, checkbox

I am having trouble displaying the correct answer/value picked in the contact form. The email received will only show C as an answer and not the picked choice.

```
<tr>
      <td><label for="gategory">Lemosine</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="carchoice[]" value="A" /><td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><label for="gategory">Mini</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="carchoice[]" value="B" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><label for="gategory">Van</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="carchoice[]" value="C" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
      <td><label for="gategory">Off-Road</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="carchoice[]" value="D" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><label for="gategory">Station-car</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="carchoice[]" value="E" /></td>
  </tr>
```

And the PHP code

```
$check_box_values = "Check box value: ";
  if(isset($_POST['carchoice'])){
    foreach($_POST['carchoice'] as $value){
    $check_box_values .= $value;
    $check_box_values .= ', ';
  }
}


$msg=
  'Name:    '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
  Email:    '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
  IP:   '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />

  IP:   '.$check_box_values['carchoice[]'].'<br /><br />

  Message:<br /><br />

  '.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';
```

This is what i get in the email

```
Name:   awdawd aw
Email:  adasda@live.dk
IP:         195.249.185.254

IP:         C

Message:

awdawdawdd awd awdawd awd awd
```

Don't understand what i going wrong here?

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: $check_box_values is not even an array but you are trying to access it as one. Just writing $check_box_values should be enough to get it working.

Comment: `$check_box_values['carchoice[]']` should just be `$check_box_values` as you already extracted the checked fields?

Answer (score 0):

The value of check box is set as 'C' so C will be fetched, as you have labels on each try giving the label name in checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you're trying to access properties of `$check_box_values` as if it were an array, when in fact, it's a string. As a result, PHP will return the character at the position specified between the square brackets, as this is also a string, it tries to cast it as integer, resulting in 0 (so it's basically returning the character at position 0 in `$check_box_values` which is `C`).

#### [Read: String access and modification by character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Also, you don't need to loop to build the string of values, you can use `implode()`:

```
if (isset($_POST['carchoice'])) {
    $val = implode(', ', $_POST['carchoice']);
    $check_box_values = "Check box value(s): " . $val;
}
```

Comment: Wait, it did not work or maybe i did it wrong? Now i just get: Name: ffawef awefawef
Email: fwefwerf@live.dk
IP: 195.249.185.254

Catgegori: Check box value(s): 

Message:

awd awdawdadawd

Comment: Using '.$check_box_values.' gives me Check box value(s): without the the picked value